# Emacs Mode to edit template toolkit files

Tags: major-mode, minor-mode, web-mode, perl

Is there a mode to edit [template toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org) files ?

Web-Mode works decently, but maybe some modes can be combined to proved some specific Perl-editing-Funcitonality?